# Boto package installed with pip not showing up in list

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Package is boto (Amazon AWS).

```
(myvirtualenv)$ pip install --target /Users/me/Projects/myproject boto
Downloading/unpacking boto
Downloading boto-2.30.0.tar.gz (7.1MB): 7.1MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package boto
...
Successfully installed boto
Cleaning up...
(myvirtualenv)$ pip list
bpython (0.12)
Django (1.6.1)
mock (1.0.1)
PIL (1.1.7)
pip (1.4.1)
Pygments (1.6)
python-dateutil (2.2)
selenium (2.39.0)
setuptools (0.9.8)
six (1.4.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
(myvirtualenv)$
```

No boto is listed.  Nothing interesting in the pip log.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you just don't use `--target`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not installing it as part of your python installation.  You are installing the package to a specific directory using the `--target` option.

Without the `--target` option, your package would be installed to the site-packages directory of your python installation.

You find your site-packages directory(s) like this:

```
~$ python
>>> import site
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['<path>', ...]
>>>
```

`pip list` shows the pip installed packages in site-packages.

In other words, your package boto is not "installed" at all, and you won't be able to do the following without getting an error:

```
~$ python
>>> import boto
>>>
```

Unless you happen to be in the `/Users/me/Projects/myproject` directory at the time.

Comment: I need to install it in the local folder since this is what gets deployed (to google app engine in my case). Perhaps the solution is to install it in both the local folder and in the virtual env's site-packages?

Comment: Why is it a problem that it does not appear when you run `pip list`?

Comment: Exactly like you said, I can only import boto from the folder I did the install in.

Comment: Ah, then yes, you need to install it properly (to access it on the local system) AND install it to your deployment directory (to add it to your deployment directory)

Answer (score 1):

Installing boto3 using below shows boto3 in the list.

sudo python -m pip install boto3